# Get occurence between @ and textarea current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get the word after `@` depending on the current writing position of a `textarea`. More precisely:

- if the current cursor position is on any letter of `@<user>`, the answer should be `<user>`
- if the current cursor position is on any other word, the answer should be empty `''`

I'm struggling with this, but don't find any "nice" way to do it.

```js
$('#hey').on('click', function() { alert(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="chat">hello @user it's me this is a long text, here is another @username cheers!</textarea>
<span id="hey">CLICK ME</span>
```

Comment: @mplungjan that's precisely with what i was struggling and trying to modify, isn't there a totally different way?

Comment: Just test to see if the word contains @ or not. And why not tell us the code you already tried?

Comment: It was a long piece of non-working code (see in my other questions, i usually post what i've tried, but here it's ugly and pointless).

Comment: If you struggled with the answer I put as duplicate, I would have waited with marking as duplicate. What does not work for you with the code in that answer?

Comment: The things I tried were similar to the links given by your first comment. On the other hand, the duplicate question seems to solve the problem :) Thanks for pointing me this. Only problem : see bug/comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600971/1422096 Do you have any idea @mplungjan?

Comment: Perhaps `var end = this.value.indexOf(' ',caret.end); if (end==-1) end = textearea.value.length-1`?

Comment: Does it work? I'm on my phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having updated the code from the assumed duplicate [Get current word on caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600686/get-current-word-on-caret-position),  the result is as follows

```js
function getCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var start, end;
    if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        start = ctrl.selectionStart;
        end = ctrl.selectionEnd;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        start = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    }
}

$("textarea").on("click keyup", function () {
    var caret = getCaretPosition(this);
    var endPos = this.value.indexOf(' ',caret.end);
    if (endPos ==-1) endPos = this.value.length;
    var result = /\S+$/.exec(this.value.slice(0, endPos));
    var lastWord = result ? result[0] : null;
    if (lastWord) lastWord = lastWord.replace(/['";:,.\/?\\-]$/, ''); // remove punctuation
    $("#atID").html((lastWord && lastWord.indexOf("@") == 0)?lastWord:"");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>Follow me on twitter @mplungjan if you want</textarea><br/>
<span id="atID"></span>
```